# Synchronous Turn Based game for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm currently working on an iOS card game. It's *like* bridge but, different is some rules. Anyway, I'm currently thinking of the multiplayer aspect of this game. I can't use the iOS 5 turn-based feature as it's async, which is useless in my case. So, the question is, can this type of multiplayer games be implemented on using GameCenter API ? Or i will have to come up with my own server.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can always make async calls synchronous by blocking waiting for their response

Comment: Can that be done in iOS 5? I have no access to the sdk

Comment: How can you not have access to the sdk yet want to use a feature of it?

Comment: I'm going to buy a license in the coming few days. I'm just researching my options.

Answer (score 1):

You may start with Ray Wenderlich's great [tutor](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server)[ials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4471/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server-part-2).

Comment: I had them bookmarked until i could get the license. I'm just afraid that doing such thing wont be possible by GameCenter and i would have to write my own server

Answer (score 0):

Clearly YES. You can use Game Center for that. Turn Based Games on Game Center based on synchronous mentality. Look at here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html